# advise how to implement a code generator for asp.NET mvc 2

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, code-generation

I would like your advice about how best to solve my problem.

In a Web server is running. NET Framework 4.0. Whatever the methods and technologies you would advise me. applications built on the basis Asp.NET MVC 2.

I have a database table in MS SQL Server. For each table in database, I must implement the interface for viewing, editing, and deleting. So code generator must generate **model, controller and views.**. Generation should happen after clicking on the button in WEB UI.
as **Model** I use .NET Entity Framework.

Now, I need to generate controllers and views.

So if i have a table with name **tableN1**. and below its colums:

- [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
- [name] [nvarchar 20] NOT NULL,
- [fullName] [nvarchar 50] NOT NULL,
- [age] [int] NOT NULL
- [active] [bit] NULL

agree: if the type bit, then generate a checkbox.
nvarchar (20) - textbox
nvarchar (max)-textarea and so on.

for this table, i want to generate views and controller. thanks.

PS. solution for this problem must be **FREE**

Comment: Is this for a new project or an existing db?

Comment: @Chance, db structure created by constructor from WEB UI. and I want that after creating table structure by user, to generate simple views and controller for this table.

Comment: creating tables on the fly is risky because you are going to need to generate both the tables and the queries yourself. You won't be able to utilize an ORM because that would require recompiling the solution.

This all really depends on how fancy you want to go. T4 would likely be your best bet at this point or perhaps Dynamic Data (but I dont know if you can trigger it regurge the info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [T4 Templates](http://blogs.msdn.com/webdevtools/archive/2009/01/29/t4-templates-a-quick-start-guide-for-asp-net-mvc-developers.aspx) for this.

The Add Controller and Add View dialogs use this behind the scenes in ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [CodeSmith](http://www.codesmithtools.com/) or [t4 templates](http://blogs.msdn.com/webdevtools/archive/2009/01/29/t4-templates-a-quick-start-guide-for-asp-net-mvc-developers.aspx)

Comment: I'd agree it's generally more economical to use a paid-for 3rd party product than to write this kind of thing from scratch yourself (presuming you place any value on your time and effort).

Comment: Yes, 3rd party is often better for this kind of thing. I included the T4 link because it is a very good article to get people started on how T4 works, escpecially with MVC. It is also free.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that needs to roll their own data layer PetaPoco (http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco/) includes a set of T4 templates that generate POCOs from a database and which can be used without implementing PetaPoco.  You'll need to modify them to suit your purpose but it's significantly better than starting from scratch.